# What is the basic purpose of @SerializedName annotation in Android using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

What is the basic purpose of `@SerializedName` annotation in Android using Gson?

Give me some different examples. I can't understand the main purpose of using it.

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: i cannot understand what are say?

Comment: it will identify the property indentifier  to which this property belongs from the json data

Comment: You can see this awesome explaination https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-how-to-change-the-naming-of-fields-with-serializedname

Answer (score 308):

Java class example,

```
public class Person {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String personName;

    @SerializedName("bd")
    private String birthDate;

}
```

This class has two fields that represent the person name and birth date of a person. These fields are annotated with the **@SerializedName** annotation. The parameter (value) of this annotation is the name to be used when `serialising` and `deserialising` objects. For example, the Java field **personName** is represented as **name** in JSON.

JSON Example,

```
{
    "name":"chintan",
    "bd":"01-01-1990"
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadAli its my pleasure to help you. You can also give me credit by upvote and accept answer my dear :)

Comment: Negative voters, please add your comment so that I can understand what is purpose of down vote and I can improve my answer onwards.. :)

Comment: Good answer .... Right to the point .... Example with `Json` was helpful

Comment: Glad that it helped. :)

Comment: few more info can be found from [here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html).

Comment: @MuhammadAli if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 82):

There are already few answers here,but I would like to add that if you are using `ProGuard` to Obfuscate your code & don't use `@SerializedName("name")` in your model class, then your GSON won't work. Because due to obfuscation, your variable names might have changed from `String name` to `String a` resulting into broken GSON parsing as GSON will look for key `a` into json & it will fail.

By specifying `@SerializedName`, GSON will not look in json based on variable name & will just use specified `@SerializedName`.

Of Course you can tell proguard to not obfuscate your model, but if you would like to have model obfuscated, then you must specify `@SerializedName`

Comment: Gr8 info, I used to tell proguard to not obfuscate the models. Now, with this I can do. :)

Comment: This is very very important. Lost 2 hours and have added @SerializedName every where.

Comment: Suppose my API endpoint response has multiple index like `data`  { status : true, message : success, data :{name:demo,url: http://mysiet.com} }  , Can I use SerializedName in model like `@SerializedName("data.name")`  for getting name value

Comment: @Ajith Nope that's not possible. You'll need to create a separate class for parsing `name` and `url`

Comment: I tried that too like but when I tried it doesn't work . Canln you send an example please?

Comment: Does @JsonProperty("name") tell proguard to not obfuscate the model? I have searched a lot of places. I can't find it.

Answer (score 10):

Using @SerializedName you are actually telling the Parser when receiving a callback from the server i.e. of a Json format:

```
{
    "name":"John Doe",
}
```

that when **Serializing** or **Deserializing** an object to **instead of searching** for a key named: "userName", in the Json response, to search for "name".

```
@SerializedName("name")
var userName: String,
```

This is good because you may have a **model** that you would like it to have its members being called with whatever you like.

Answer (score 5):

You can instruct Proguard to not obfuscate your data classes by specifying @Keep on top of the class. This will neither remove nor obfuscate your class. No need to add @SerializedName to each and every field explicitly if the field name is similar to the Json key being used for it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say in a real-world scenario, your backend dev is giving you this response for an API request you make

```
{
 "name":"John Doe",
 "id":"1478"
}
```

Now, in the data class you make to handle this, there might be chances you want to specify a different variable name at Android side for the fields "name" and "id" that you are getting from backend.

**@SerializedName** comes to rescue here.

You just need to specify the actual key value you will be getting from backend in the **@SerializedName** (which will be used to serialize and deserialize) and then you can use a variable name of your choice that stores that value received from the operation.

For example, for the JSON I mentioned earlier, here is how its data class will look like:

```
data class User(
    @SerializedName("name") val userName: String,
    @SerializedName("id") val userId: Int
)
```

Here **name**, **id** is used in **@SerializedName** because it's the backend key.
But I have used **userName**, **userId** to store those values.