# Get a Json array with Retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit, pojo

Hi I'm trying to parse into a List the following JSON response

```
{"beers":[{"id":"1","nombre":"Larzobispa","localidad":"Alcorcon","provincia":"Madrid"},{"id":"2","nombre":"La Cibeles","localidad":"Madrid","provincia":"Madrid"}]}
```

Im using the following code

My interface

```
public interface AbebeerApi {
    @GET("/beer_app/beers")
    List<SingleBeer> listBeers();
}
```

Implementation of the AbebeerApi

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
     .baseUrl("end_point_url")
     .build();

AbebeerApi service = retrofit.create(AbebeerApi.class);
```

And the call for the created service

```
List<SingleBeer> beers = service.listBeers();
```

I dont get any response in beers list. My app close and I get no information in the logcat.

This is my POJO class

```
public class SingleBeer {
    int id;
    String nombre;
    String localidad;
    String provincia;

//getters and setters
    }
```

Could some one help me?
Thank you in advance

EDIT: I let you my php code in case there is something wrong with it

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
$response["beers"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $beers = array();
    $beers["id"] = $row["id"];
    $beers["nombre"] = $row["nombre"];
    $beers["localidad"] = $row["localidad"];
    $beers["provincia"] = $row["provincia"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["beers"], $beers);
}
// success
$response["succes"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
mysql_close($localhost);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No beers have found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
    mysql_close($localhost);
}
```

EDIT 2: I solved the problem with this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27698866/4669063

I created the LenientGsonConverter class I added in the setConverter method to my RestAdapter

Comment: Looks like you need to add a convertor when building your adapter.  See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32390665/1904517

Comment: Thank you for your comment but still not work with that answer....

Comment: I just change my code and use retrofit 1.9.0 but still dont work. If I use https://api.github.com/users I can get all the users in my list but when I want to get my Json it doesnt work. It has the same structure...[{"id":"1","nombre":"La arzobispa","localidad":"Alcorcon","provincia":"Madrid"},{"id":"2","nombre":"La Cibeles","localidad":"Madrid","provincia":"Madrid"}]

Answer (score 2):

```
RestAdapter retrofit= new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("end_point_url")
                .build();
AbebeerApi service = retrofit.create(AbebeerApi.class);
service.getBeer(new Callback<BeerResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void success(BeerResponse beerResponse, Response res) {
                // Use beerResponse for response
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            }
        });
```

Here is your interface. You should add Callback method. In callback you should pass your POJO.

```
public interface AbebeerApi {
    @GET("/beer_app/beers")
    public void getBeer(Callback<BeerResponse> callback)
}
```

I am answering for this api.

```
{"beers":[{"id":"1","nombre":"Larzobispa","localidad":"Alcorcon","provincia":"Madrid"},{"id":"2","nombre":"La Cibeles","localidad":"Madrid","provincia":"Madrid"}]}
```

**The problem is you are trying to pass List directly**. You should create two classes for getting response. The first one BeerResponse is only for list and in second class you should declare your json object means id ,nombre and all.Moreover the main import thing is **your api fields name and your POJO's fields name must be same.** If you want to change POJO's field name then you can use GSON annotation @SerializedName.

```
public class BeerResponse{
 List<SingleBeer> beers;

 //getters and setters
}

public class SingleBeer {
    int id;
    String nombre;
    String localidad;
    String provincia;

//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Used and still not working. Thankyou for the info. I get in the error.printStackTrace() the following error    com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 2 path $

Answer (score 1):

The structure is not exactly the same.  Your response has an object that has a field called `beers` that is a list of beers.  You need to deserialize that object --

```
class Beers {
    List<SingleBeer> beers;
}
```

Update your interface --

```
public interface AbebeerApi {
    @GET("/beer_app/beers")
    Beers listBeers();
}
```

and your call --

```
Beers beerContainer = service.listBeers();
```

And access the beer list though `beerContain.beers` or an equivalent getter.

Comment: Yes I changed my Json response to that:     [{"id":"1","nombre":"La arzobispa","localidad":"Alcorcon","provincia":"Madrid"},{"id":"2","nombre":"La Cibeles","localidad":"Madrid","provincia":"Madrid"}] to obtain the same structure (with a string id) and still not working... I tried your code too but not working. Thank you for your time,

Comment: See if you can get a logcat.  That would help narrow things down

Comment: In the service the methods succes and failure I know that the code runs through the failure obtaining my log in the logcat. @Override
 public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
 Log.i("TEST", "ERROR");}. I let you my url if you could see something wrong http://abdevelopers.site88.net/beer_app/beers/

Comment: Try putting an `error.printStackTrace()` in your on failure method to see why retrofit is unhappy with the request.

Comment: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 2 path This error is what i get from the error.printStackTrace()

Comment: Are you still getting that error?  Looking at your link above, there is an an analytics tag on the response as well that starts on line 2, that could be messing things up.

Comment: Yes i solved my problem with that post http://stackoverflow.com/a/27698866/4669063. I created the LenientGsonConverter class I added in the setConverter method to my RestAdapter. And thank you very much to your help, you guide me in the right direction :)