# Android ViewModel has no zero argument constructor, Kotlin Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger

I am trying to make an app with API calls, but when I launch, it crashes with error, searched all over the Internet and couldn't find whats wrong.
Here is an error:

> *Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.lobo.lobo.ViewModels.DishesViewModel> has no zero argument constructor *

My project structure:

[image: my project]

My code:

DishApplication.kt:

```
package com.lobo

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class DishApplication:Application() {
}
```

api.models:

```
class DishList : ArrayList<DishListItem>()

data class DishListItem(
    val activeCount: Int,
    val actualPrice: Int,
    val description: String,
    val dishId: Int,
    val isLobobox: Int,
    val name: String,
    val orders: List<Order>,
    val originalPrice: Int,
    val photo: String,
    val tags: List<String>
)

data class Order(
    val actualPrice: Int,
    val customerId: String,
    val orderId: Int,
    val originalPrice: Int,
    val status: String
)
```

api.requests.GetDishList:

```
import com.lobo.lobo.data.api.APIConstants
import retrofit2.http.GET
import com.lobo.lobo.data.api.models.DishList
import retrofit2.http.Header

interface GetDishList {

    @GET(APIConstants.DISH_LIST)
    suspend fun getDishes(@Header("Authorization") authHeader: String): DishList

}
```

APIConstants:

```
object APIConstants {
    const val BASE_URL = "my_server_link"
    const val DISH_LIST = "list_dishes"
}
```

data.repository.DishRepo:

```
class DishRepo @Inject constructor(
    private val dishList : GetDishList
){
    suspend fun getDishList(authHeader: String) : DishList{
        return dishList.getDishes(authHeader)
    }
}
```

lobo.di.DishAPIModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DishAPIModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGetDishList(retrofit: Retrofit): GetDishList {
        return retrofit.create(GetDishList::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIConstants.BASE_URL)
            .build()
    }

}
```

lobo.ViewModels.DishesViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class DishesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dishRepo: DishRepo
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _dishes = MutableLiveData<DishList>()
    val dishes: LiveData<DishList> = _dishes

    fun getDishes(authHeader: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val dishList = dishRepo.getDishList(authHeader)
            _dishes.postValue(dishList)
        }
    }
}
```

Dishes.kt(snippet):

```
@Composable
fun ListOfDishesScreen(navController: NavController) {
    var showDialog by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var checkedState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val viewModel: DishesViewModel = viewModel()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.getDishes("Bearer my_token")
        Log.d("WTF", "token send")
    }

    val dishes by viewModel.dishes.observeAsState()
//some code here
                dishes?.forEach { dish ->
                    DishAPICard(
                        dishName = dish.name,
                        dishPhoto = dish.photo ,  // You will need to load the image from the URL.
                        actualPrice = dish.actualPrice,
                        navController = navController
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                }
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val is_auth = false
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            NavHost(navController, startDestination = if (is_auth) "lol" else "dish_list") {
                composable("dish_list"){ ListOfDishesScreen(navController = navController)}
```

and also adding my build gradle files(mb there is an error with dependency, i tried everything)

build.gradle(Project):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.2.0'
        hilt_version = '2.43'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.43' apply false
}
```

build.gradle(Module :app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'



android {
    namespace 'com.lobo.lobo'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lobo.lobo"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.17.0'
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets:0.17.0"// Please use the latest version



    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.2"

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.43'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.43'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.43'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.43"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"

    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'  // Make sure you use the latest version
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.3.1'  // Make sure you use the latest version
}
```

Full error message with the stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lobo.lobo, PID: 24136
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.lobo.lobo.ViewModels.DishesViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:322)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:304)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:278)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:215)
        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:156)
        at com.lobo.lobo.DishesKt.ListOfDishesScreen(Dishes.kt:386)
        at com.lobo.lobo.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1$2$11.invoke(MainActivity.kt:67)
        at com.lobo.lobo.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1$2$11.invoke(MainActivity.kt:67)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:163)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:141)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$4$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:115)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$4$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:124)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:55)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:141)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2351)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2641)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:248)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:247)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:177)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$4.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$4.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2351)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2618)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3205)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3183)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:252)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3183)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:746)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:876)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:485)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:454)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:970)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:727)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@875fdae, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@1c374f, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@af7cedc, AndroidUiDispatcher@6b24be5]
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.lobo.lobo.ViewModels.DishesViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
            ... 86 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24136 SIG: 9
```

I tried changing dependencies, and my `@Composable` objects but still the same error

Comment: You should provide full error message with the stack trace to help address the problem.

Comment: @nope i provided, please review again, code with `hiltViewModel()` didn't work

Comment: Is the log with the ``hiltViewModel``? and what's on line 386 at ``Dishes.kt``?

Comment: @nope, with  `hiltViewModel` I get an error: `Unresolved reference: hiltViewModel`, there is no line 386 at `Dishes.kt`, but when I click in console at this line(Navigate to inline function call site), it gives me a line with `val viewModel: DishesViewModel = viewModel()`

Comment: Do you declare `DishApplication` in the `<application` in manifest? Also try to upgrade Hilt to 2.46?

Comment: @Vleo try my new answer, or the previous if you were to put it as a parameter.

Comment: @nope `Unresolved reference: viewModels`, I changed to `val viewModel: DishesViewModel by viewModel()`, but it didn't work

Comment: @TheLibrarian, I added i manifest this `<application
   android:name="com.lobo.DishApplication"`, and upgraded Hilt to 2.46, but still this `Unresolved reference: hiltViewModel`

Comment: you can go to the docs [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.htm) to learn about hiltViewModels and [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup) about the setup.
make sure you got the dependencies right.

Comment: I think that you should change ``id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'`` to ``id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'`` like in the docs and the other build file.
than you can try with the methods before

Comment: @nope when i paste `val viewModel: DishesViewModel by viewModels()`  in MainActivity where i have `@AndroidEntryPoint` it isn't showing `Unresolved reference: viewModels`, but i have NavHost there, what should i do?

Comment: I think you better do ``@Composable
fun ListOfDishesScreen(
navController: NavController,
viewModel: DishesViewModel = hiltViewModel()
)
``

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. I copied your build.gradle and was able run it without a hiccup. If you create completely new project and copy only build.gradle and would create quick dummy view model, does this happen too?

Comment: @TheLibrarian can you share your code pls, github maybe?

Comment: @nope i still get this `Unresolved reference: hiltViewModel` whe i change to `Composable fun ListOfDishesScreen( navController: NavController, viewModel: DishesViewModel = hiltViewModel() ) `

Comment: I can replicate your stack exactly but the only way is if I delete `@HiltViewModel` from the View model file. Is there any chance that you have something else declaring that annotation? (correct one - `dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel`)

Comment: I mean here is the [repo](https://github.com/TheLibrarianCz/HiltVMSO) but I really didn't change anything really. The only thing that caught my eye from the comments was `android:name="com.lobo.DishApplication` - the path doesn't seem to match your package structure but then the error would be different.

Comment: @TheLibrarian I deleted `@HiltViewModel` from `DishesViewModel`, and now my error is `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.lobo.lobo.ViewModels.DishesViewModel`, also if i add  `@HiltViewModel` it is the same error. It is crahsing at this point `fun ListOfDishesScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel: DishesViewModel = viewModel()`, i can't use viewModels() outside MainActivity, and hiltViewModel at all (`Unresolved reference`)

Comment: Yeah, that is expected because `hiltViewModel` is from `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0` that wasn't in your Gradle file, Have you tired my repo?

Comment: @TheLibrarian i fixed `Cannot create an instance`, with hiltViewModel, but now i have another error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.lobo.lobo.data.api.models.DishList`

Comment: You are not providing any converters - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367469/unable-to-create-converter-for-my-class-in-android-retrofit-library.

Comment: @TheLibrarian I added `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` to `provideRetrofit()`, now I am having another error(when responce comes): `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

Comment: Well, is the response in JSON format? Also, you must label `DishItem` as `@Serializable`. `DishList` seems unnecessary. `List<DishItem>` is enough.

Comment: @TheLibrarian and nope thank you guys!

Comment: I have almost the same situation about year ago. Try to instantiate viewModel inside onCreate() but before setContentView. `viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DishesViewModel::class)`

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need to change

```
val viewModel: DishesViewModel = viewModel()
```

to

```
val viewModel: DishesViewModel by viewModels()
```

in `Dishes.kt`.

Comment: There doesn't really seem to be a difference in regards to Hilt knowing how to instantiate them.

Comment: You're partially right, fixing my answer

Comment: Whether it is by delegate doesn't matter. Also `by viewModels()` is something completely different than `= viewModel()`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing provide method in the module. Your viewModel depends upon repository and you annotated hilt to provide this dependency. Hilt cannot provide dependency that it cannot found in the module of that component.

```
 @Module
 @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
 object DishAPIModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideGetDishList(retrofit: Retrofit): GetDishList {
    return retrofit.create(GetDishList::class.java)
    }

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(APIConstants.BASE_URL)
        .build()
    }

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideDishRepo(dishList : GetDishList): DishRepo {
    return DishRepo(dishList)
    }

}
```

Now hilt can provide DishRepo object to the viewModel as it knows it.

Comment: Just because the class Hilt is supposed to provide is not in a module doesn't mean that it doesn't see it. @Inject is enough.