# Using retrofit Send this JSON to the server POST

Tags: android, gson

```
{

    "first_name": "yy",
    "last_name": "uu",
    "mobile": "123456",
    "email": "qwerty32@g.com",
    "user_type":"user",
    "bio": "hell",
    "expertise_json": {"0":"1", "1":"2"}

}
```

This is the Josn i have to send, 
My java classe for this user:

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String userEmail;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String userPassword;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    private String userFirstName;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    private String userLastName;
    @SerializedName("mobile")
    private String userMobile;
    @SerializedName("user_type")
    private String userType;

    @SerializedName("expertise_json")
    @Expose
    private HashMap<String,String> userExpertise;

    @SerializedName("bio")
    private String bio;
   }

public interface ApiInterface {

    @POST("register")
    Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
    @GET("init")
    Call<Expertises> getExpertise();

}
```

everything is saving to server except expertise_json. Also expertise_json is dynamic not limited to 2 or 3 values but can be any 10 20 etc. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: replace `@SerializedName("expertise_json")` with `@SerializedName("expertise")`.

Comment: it is not `expertise_json` , it is `expertise` . change the name and your response send .

Comment: highly recommend you use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ this for convert your json to POJO. so you make less error. as above said serializedName is wrong

Comment: post your interface class

Comment: NO, this expertise_json is dynamic can be 1 2 3 4 5. .... so on

Comment: interface class posted

Answer (score 1):

Replace your User class with this:

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("email")
private String userEmail;
@SerializedName("password")
private String userPassword;
@SerializedName("first_name")
private String userFirstName;
@SerializedName("last_name")
private String userLastName;
@SerializedName("mobile")
private String userMobile;
@SerializedName("user_type")
private String userType;

@SerializedName("expertise")
@Expose
private HashMap<String,String> userExpertise;

@SerializedName("bio")
private String bio;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
@SerializedName("expertise")
@Expose
private Expertise expertise;
```

**Expertise.java**

```
public class Expertise {

@SerializedName("0")
@Expose
private String _0;
@SerializedName("1")
@Expose
private String _1;

public String get0() {
return _0;
}

public void set0(String _0) {
this._0 = _0;
}

public String get1() {
return _1;
}

public void set1(String _1) {
this._1 = _1;
}
```

Comment: No expertsie_json is dynamic this pojo will not work if values increase to 3 4 5 etc

Answer (score 0):

I see "**@SerializedName**" in you code, so gson should be used.
Here is a link saying what is the basic purpose of @SerializedName annotation.

[what is the basic purpose of @SerializedName annotation in android using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957285/what-is-the-basic-purpose-of-serializedname-annotation-in-android-using-gson)

So, when you use @SerializedName, that means you specify the value of a field using the value of a specific tag in json. For your case, which means the field **userExpertise** using the value of **expertise_json** in json, which does not existed at all. The solution can be changing **expertise_json** into **expertise**

```
public class User {

  @SerializedName("email")       private String userEmail;
  @SerializedName("password")    private String userPassword;
  @SerializedName("first_name")  private String userFirstName;
  @SerializedName("last_name")   private String userLastName;
  @SerializedName("mobile")      private String userMobile;
  @SerializedName("user_type")   private String userType;

  @SerializedName("expertise") 
  @Expose
  private HashMap<String,String> userExpertise;

  @SerializedName("bio") private String bio;

}
```

---

**ADD:**
Here: In you code.

```
public interface ApiInterface {

  @POST("register")
  Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);  // watch this param, 'User user'

  ...
```

Now, let's go back to the json file

```
{
  "status": true,
  "body": {
     "first_name": "yy",
     ...
     "expertise_json": {"0":"1", "1":"2"}
  }
}
```

Here is the problem:
You are sending a body, whose content is a **User**, and as a **User**, it has the field of **userEmail**, **userType** and etc, but do not has the field of **status**, do not has the field of **body**.

So you wanna gson works, you should provide a class that contains these fields.

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("status")    private boolean status;
    @SerializedName("body")      private Body body;

    public static class Body {
        @SerializedName("email")       private String userEmail;
        @SerializedName("password")    private String userPassword;
        @SerializedName("first_name")  private String userFirstName;
        @SerializedName("last_name")   private String userLastName;
        @SerializedName("mobile")      private String userMobile;
        @SerializedName("user_type")   private String userType;

        @SerializedName("expertise") 
        @Expose
        private HashMap<String,String> userExpertise;

        @SerializedName("bio") private String bio;
    }
 }
```

It should work now.

Comment: I replaced expertise_json to expertise but still not working, I need to use HashMap for expertise because these values expertise_json are dynamic can be more then 2 like 5 or 10 etc

Comment: I have used gson to decode your json, and the **userExpertise** has 2 key-value.

Comment: No expertise still not going to database, everything else is going