# how to convert json property like "oData.type" to java object

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to convert below JSON string to a Java Object

```
String json = "{\"odata.type\":\"SP.Data.UserInfoItem\",\"odata.id\":\"479655bd-324f-4584-b6b21e6c1777ad6\",\"Id\":735,\"Name\":\"i:0#.f|membership|xxxxx@xxxxx.com\",\"Title\":\"xxxxx\"}";

convertStringToJavaPbject(json);
```

Here is my java method

```
private static void convertStringToJavaPbject(String json) {

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    JsonElement jElement = gson.fromJson(json,JsonElement.class);

    Auther auther = gson.fromJson(jElement, Auther.class);
    System.out.println(" Auther : ["+auther);

}
```

and my Auther pojo is

```
public class Auther {

 private String odatatype;
 private String odataid;
 private String name;
 private String title;
 private int id;

public String getOdatatype() {
    return odatatype;
}
public void setOdatatype(String odatatype) {
    this.odatatype = odatatype;
}
public String getOdataid() {
    return odataid;
}
public void setOdataid(String odataid) {
    this.odataid = odataid;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Auther [odatatype=" + odatatype + ", odataid=" + odataid
            + ", name=" + name + ", title=" + title + ", id=" + id + "]";
}

}
```

How can I get the value of "`odata.type`" in my class since I cannot declare a variable with as "`odata.type`"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957285/what-is-the-basic-purpose-of-serializedname-annotation-in-android-using-gson