# Access JSON value called "class" with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am trying to get the value of class in the following JSON:

```
{    
    "battlegroup": "Misery",
    "class": 1,
    "race": 4,
    "gender": 0
}
```

I access the other fields (`battlegroup`, `race` etc.) with:

```java
WoWDetails info = gson.fromJson(response, WoWDetails.class);
raceID = info.race;
```

WoWDetails is as following:

```
class WoWDetails {
// character details
   public String battlegroup;
   public Integer achievementPoints;
   public Integer race;
   public Integer class;
}
```

But if I try `WoWDetails.class` it's giving me an error saying "Unknown class: info". Which makes sense because info is not a class.

Is there a way around this? Can I escape the word "class" in any way possible?

The name class is not editable, since it's not my API.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957285/what-is-the-basic-purpose-of-serializedname-annotation-in-android-using-gson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your Package name

```
package com.nonprofit.nonprofit;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class WoWDetails {

    @SerializedName("battlegroup")
    @Expose
    private String battlegroup;
    @SerializedName("class")
    @Expose
    private Integer _class;
    @SerializedName("race")
    @Expose
    private Integer race;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    private Integer gender;

    public String getBattlegroup() {
        return battlegroup;
    }

    public void setBattlegroup(String battlegroup) {
        this.battlegroup = battlegroup;
    }

    public Integer getClass_() {
        return _class;
    }

    public void setClass_(Integer _class) {
        this._class = _class;
    }

    public Integer getRace() {
        return race;
    }

    public void setRace(Integer race) {
        this.race = race;
    }

    public Integer getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Integer gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

You can get your details like below

```
WoWDetails info = gson.fromJson(response, WoWDetails.class);

info.getGender();
info.getRace();
```

Comment: Is "info.getClasses_" supposed to be with underscore? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: you will be able to get your value in info.getClass_();

Comment: You can get your getter and setter from this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @R.Montanje `class` is a reserved word and the way you though it should work causes Java syntax errors.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it was, I just needed a way around it, and I got it :)

Comment: Class is java default keyword so if creating a getter and setter need to set_.

Answer (score 3):

You can map the `class` field to JSON key using `@SerializedName`

**WowDetails.java**

```
public class WoWDetails {

    String battlegroup;

    @SerializedName("class")
    int className;

    int race;
    int gender;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But the other answer did too, which one do I accept? *General question*

Comment: To be fair, this deserves to be upvoted just because this is not a jsonschema2pojo copy/paste.

Comment: Always accept the answer which explains the answer so that you can learn.

Comment: Okay, thanks! They're both good answers, the 1st one has more explanation. But they worked both for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty surprised that this answer was not accepted.