# Gson().fromJson returns null in Android

Tags: android, json, gson, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an error message I get from an api, this is my string:

```
{"Message":"Ya existe un usuario registrado con ese email"}
```

But when I call Gson like this it returns a `NetworkError` with null values:

```
String message = new Gson().fromJson(jsonMessage, NetworkError.class).getMessage();
```

I have been looking at similar questions and realize there has to be something wrong in the `NetworkError` class but I can't figure out what it is. Here is the class:

```
public class NetworkError {

    private String message;

    public NetworkError(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() { return message; }
}
```

I have tried by including a set method and an empty constructor but I still got null.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `NetworkError.java` class, try changing your `message` variable in the class to `Message`, since that is the key you are receiving in the REST response and it might be causing issues when mapping the key.

I can understand that you still might want to use camel case for your variable names. You can use `@SerializedName` annotation to keep your variable name anything you want but still have GSON map to it. You can read more on [what is the basic purpose of @SerializedName annotation in android using GSon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957285/what-is-the-basic-purpose-of-serializedname-annotation-in-android-using-gson)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tip about using the annotation

Answer (score 2):

Keys in JSON are case sensitive. Therefore, Gson is looking for the "message" key, which is not there (you are using the "Message" key).

You can just do:

```
@SerializedName("Message")
private String message;
```