# Match dynamic serialized name with gson

Tags: android, arrays, json, wikipedia-api, gson

I'm parsing wikipedia API data, but don't get how to deal with changing serialized name on every new search request. It's always the first item of "pages" array (1156934). I am making request using Q204873 wiki data code to get page title, for example "Ammonium carbonate". But I don't know wikipedia pageID (1156934) before request.

[image: wikipedia response]

[This response URL query](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=wblistentityusage&wbeuentities=Q204873&wbeuprop=url&wbeulimit=1)

---

My gson model with marked problem (1156934 would fit here, but it changes as I make request with different wikidata Q code during new search query):

```
public class WikiPageList {

@SerializedName("WikiPage") //PROBLEM
private WikiPage wikiPage;

public void setWikiPage(WikiPage wikiPage){
    this.wikiPage = wikiPage;
}

public WikiPage getWikiPage(){
    return wikiPage;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "WikiPageList{" +
        "WikiPage = '" + wikiPage + '\'' +
        "}";
    }
```

}

---

How can I only deserialize first item of pages array? I can also supply multiple Q codes to receive multiple titles, but how to use same gson model for every array item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the basic purpose of @SerializedName annotation in android using GSon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957285/what-is-the-basic-purpose-of-serializedname-annotation-in-android-using-gson)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I know the purpose of @SerializedName and I use it to match title, pageid, etc in this example. But I can't extract this page first to be able to deserialize page futher as the pageID changes on every new request!

Comment: You need to create your own number deserialzer and register it with gson. Look at this example. let me know if you cannot understand.
https://gist.github.com/peerapongsam/a7771e49562d74843c64f9cf53adbe52

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HashMap when you don't know the data key values in json

Use like below

@SerializedName("pages")
public HashMap pages

You can also use custom deserializer to make it work

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics

Comment: Would you be able to provide more implementation examples of HashMap and explanation about what it is? That's new for me.

Comment: Use this as a basic example http://findnerd.com/list/view/Parse-Json-Object-with-dynamic-keys-using-Gson-/24094/