# How to access the value of a key inside a key in a JSON response in android fetched with Retrofit2?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I'm accessing a WordPress API to fetch the posts using Retrofit2, then when I try to assign the values to the views in my adapter:

```
inner class MainActivityViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(post: Post) {
        with(post) {
            itemView.tv_post_title.text = title
            itemView.tv_post_date.text = date
            itemView.tv_post_content.text = content
        }
    }
}
```

The Retrofit's `GET` returns an `Observable`, and thus, the following error in `onErrorResumeNext` is shown when it tries to assign:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 373 path $[0].title

This is because `title` key has a `rendered` key within it:

```
{  
  id:497,
  date:"2018-04-08T03:34:12",
  [...]
  title:{  
    rendered:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  }
}
```

The same applies to `content` and `excerpt`. How do I access these `rendered`s keys? I tried something like

> val title: JsonElement = JsonParser().parse(post.title)

but the same error persists.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Made some alterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because json parser is not able to parse the title object.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 373 path $[0].title

To avoid this runtime error, [click here to create java pojo for expected json](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and then use it as return type in your retrofit api.

Try using following java pojo for your json which is created using above mentioned tool.

Post.kt

```
data class Post(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Embedded
    val title: Title,

    @SerializedName("excerpt")
    @Embedded
    val excerpt: Excerpt,

    @SerializedName("content")
    @Embedded
    val content: Content,

    @SerializedName("date")
    val date: String,

    @SerializedName("modified")
    val modified: String
)
```

Content.kt

```
class Content {
    @SerializedName("rendered")
    var content: String? = null
}
```

Title.kt

```
class Title {
    @SerializedName("rendered")
    var title: String? = null
}
```

Excerpt.kt

```
class Excerpt {
    @SerializedName("rendered")
    var excerpt: String? = null
}
```

Import following dependency for Gson

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
```

> @SerializedName: Give the ability to map JSON key with java member variable with a different name than JSON key.
>   [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957285/what-is-the-basic-purpose-of-serializedname-annotation-in-android-using-gson)

Comment: Hey, it actually helped. But it leads to another problem. Since I have more than one field with `rendered` as sub-key, if naming many @Embedded classes to `rendered`, it will complain about it saying "Multiple fields have the same columnName: rendered". Renaming them differently will not read the value.

Comment: Can you please give more details about error and sample json you are trying to parse?

Comment: The issue is just like `title: { rendered: "foo" } }`, but there are 2 other keys with `rendered` inside,  `content` and `excerpt`, and this causes the error `Error:(8, 8) error: Multiple fields have the same columnName: rendered. Field names: title > rendered, content > rendered, excerpt > rendered.`. I found solutions to append prefixes, but in this case, they were creating their JSON format, in my case, I fetch a format that is already defined, and a different name than `rendered` will not show anything. If you want to see the JSON: http://skillpoint.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

Comment: @gamofe Please check edited answer. Use Gson or any other similar parser if you want to manipulate JSON mapping. Since mapped variables are different from JSON keys, therefore error should go.

Comment: Using GSON's `SerializedName` solved it. Just one thing for you to edit in your answer: the name of the variables in the other 3 classes cannot be the same, only the serialized name should be `rendered`.

Comment: @gamofe I'm glad this worked out. Can you please edit the answer?

Comment: Yes, I just finished doing so.